# JMeter HTML Report Dashboard - Number of Total Errors is greater than Number of Total Samples

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I just run a JMeter Test using JMeter 5.1.1, after the test is completed JMeter HTML Report Dashboard is generated. Awesome.

But looking at the numbers , especially in the section "Top 5 Errors by Sampler" , I see this

[image]

Number of errors are divided into 5 columns , each column denotes one type of error.

Why is the number of total errors is greater than the number of samples ?
I understand if the number of samples is equal or greater than the total number of errors. 
But how come the total numbers of errors is greater than the total number of samples ?  It doesn't make sense.

Is this a bug or something wrong on my side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you calculated or sumed the Total Errors into Errors specified per as different citeria.

Clasification :

[image: JmeterErrors]

So, the **Total Errors : 1236527** is the sum of the **different errors count by criteria**. So you shouldn't add the Total Errors count with error counts by criteria. Thus your **Total Errors : 1236527** is not greater than **Total Samplers : 1904035** .

Hope, this resolves your confusion .